# 32-bit driver on a 64-bit system

Tags: 10.04, printing

I have a printer Lexmark X6675.  The only driver available for it is 32-bit but I want to run a 64-bit system.  Is there any way to use the native [driver](http://support.lexmark.com/index?page=content&actp=DD_LIST&productCode=LEXMARK_X6675&id=DR20523&os=UBUNTU_9.04&oslocale=en_US&segment=DOWNLOAD&userlocale=EN_US&locale=en) supplied by Lexmark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the X6550. You might have good luck also using **getlibs**. (It has always operated "magically" well for me.) If getlibs is available in the 10.04 repos, you can install it like so:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

If not, download getlibs from http://frozenfox.freehostia.com/cappy/getlibs-all.deb or search for an alternate location and then install the DEB package:

```
sudo dpkg -i getlibs-all.deb
```

Then you run it...

```
sudo getlibs program_name
```

It finds, downloads, and installs all of the 32-bit libs needed for applications.
You can also do it for libraries...

```
sudo getlibs -l libxxx-yyy.so.1
```

Success?

Comment: Was in process of posting that. See also http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/534 and http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=474790

Comment: @bodhi.zazen ha! beat ya for once :) btw - kudos on your ad block script! love it!

Comment: glad you like the adblock script =)

Comment: Will test as soon as I get the environment to do this with.